# Get authorization from Lumen and header from Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, request, http-headers, lumen

In project, all API calls are from Lumen. Front is developed in Laravel. We are calling Lumen APIs using Guzzle http client [guzzleHttp](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Now, I need to set header Authorization for all API calls so I'm sending token in header from Laravel but in Lumen I can't get token in Lumen request header.

Below is the example code.

Laravel controller code:

```
public function get_category(){


    $accessToken = 'kjdhfdkjfhdkjfhfjkdf9875443213456';


    $response = \Guzzle::request("GET","example.com", "categories",['headers' => [
        'Authorization' => $accessToken
    ]]);

    $category_all = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);

    return $category_all;

}
```

Lumen middleware code:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

   dd($request);

}
```

In Lumen request I can't get token in request header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Apache, by default it remove the *Authorization* header.
You've to add this settings in the `.htaccess` project's file or in the apache `.conf`  file (usually in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
```